# Is there a way to prevent {} 1 Fields from being printed and print the inner value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am querying a mongodb using mongodb compass, and I cannot print the value in table form, it always prints {} 1 Fields..I want to print the value inside as a table.   The same thing happens when i use mongoexport

[image: Here is the original json structure]

[image: Here is the query structure]

[image: These are the results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the aggregation pipeline, as I show you in the image below:
[image]

Another option is to use Robo3T (Ex Robomongo) with the following query:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([ { '$addFields': {'birthdayValue': '$formAnswer.birthday.value'}}, {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'roleID': 1, 'birthdayValue': 1}}])
```

You will get something as this other image shows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because project in `find()` command doesn't normalise the object structure. So the output field returned for birthday will still be an object with only 1 field. Something like `{roleID: 9, formAnswers : { birthday : { value : "06/29/1981 17:04:29"}}}`

To get the output that you are expecting you should use aggregation pipeline, which can make it a top level field. Something like `db.coll.aggregate({$project : {roleID:1, birthday : "$formAnswers.birthday.value"}})`